# Mapping array to schema in resolver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

With GraphQL, I have the following Launchpad where I can get the result of a single object, with no issues:

https://launchpad.graphql.com/xqnxw308xl

However, when I try to apply the same concept but instead return an array of all "characters" I receive the error:

```
"Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.getCharacters."
```

https://launchpad.graphql.com/qxm0m79xpp

Within the resolver, I'd like to understand how to map the array of "characters" that are returned from the API to my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the API you're calling looks like this:

```
{
    "count": 87, 
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
            "height": "172", 
            "mass": "77", 
        },
    ]
}
```

That's the object you're returning from the resolver, which, as the error indicates, isn't an Iterable so GraphQL doesn't know how to handle it. You need to transform the API result before returning it, like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getCharacters: () => {
      return fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json.results);
    }
  },
  Character: {
    // transform specific fields here
  }
}
```

Note that the resolver for the `name` field is no longer needed since the field's name matches the property name of each `Character` object returned by the `getCharacters` resolver.